# IE9 - CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error

Tags: internet-explorer, css, fonts, google-webfonts

I embed three Google Fonts from http://www.google.com/webfonts (Dosis, Open Sans, Lato)

And they all work fine except IE9 where it returns:

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
2HG_tEPiQ4Z6795cGfdivPY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot

CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
KlmP_Vc2zOZBldw8AfXD5g.eot

CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
zLhfkPOm_5ykmdm-wXaiuw.eot
```

And breaks entire website occasionally.

What can be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found this answer, which addresses the question more directly than the accepted answer, which really, shouldn't have been the answer :)

> And now to our main highlight - the "CSS3111: @font-face encountered
>   unknown error". This error is very ambiguous. If you have a look at
>   MSDN again, you'll see its description says: "An unknown problem was
>   encountered with the "Web Open Font Format (WOFF)", and "Embedded
>   OpenType font (EOT)" of the Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) font".
>   "Unknown Problem" doesn't sound too good to me - how am I supposed to
>   solve an unknown problem? Fortunately we're given a hint here. It
>   says: "Check source of the fonts". Indeed, CSS3111 is usually caused
>   by an issue with the font's binary source. One of the popular online
>   TTF to EOT converters for example produces EOT files with a NAME table
>   that doesn't comply to the Microsoft standards, which results in EOT
>   fonts that never load in IE and produce the CSS3111 error. So, when
>   you experience a CSS3111, it is always good to try using a different
>   TTF to EOT converter or font face generator.

Source: http://www.marinbezhanov.com/web-development/16/how-to-embed-webfonts-properly-and-how-to-solve-the-ambiguous-css3111-font-face-encountered-unknown-error/

Comment: Based on my experience, the experience of the OP, and the experience of Victor S at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559592/ie9-css3111-font-face-encountered-unknown-error#comment19491377_11559725, it seems like Lato is the culprit. What do you do, then? Pick a different font?

Comment: Just an idea - maybe check whether the license of the font allows modifying it, and then fix it?

Comment: I found this web site that convert fonts compatible with IE, it works for me: https://onlinefontconverter.com/

Comment: Here's another idea (in 2016) -- if you're not trying to support crusty-ass IE versions, just nuke the .eot files. Any version of IE not created before the last bubble burst will just load your `.otf`s or `.woff`s instead.

Comment: Fixed it with font-squirrel generator. [link](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

Comment: @ericsoco solution worked for me. Removed the .eot and then no more error in IE11. This was using Open-Iconic fonts.

Comment: The link provided in the answer, does not exist.(not working)

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem on IE 9 using the below `@font-face`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Gidole;
    src: url('Gidole-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('Gidole-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We've found that you get the same error due to a new Windows 10 policy. If your error occurs on Windows 10 + IE11, the solution can be this:

[IE 11: error CSS3111 in my own code, and google.com/fonts doesn't render any fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023461/ie-11-error-css3111-in-my-own-code-and-google-com-fonts-doesnt-render-any-fon)

Answer (score 1):

Commenting out the 2nd source declaration for the EOT font worked for me. Make sure you the 1st declaration right above "src: url("../fonts/webfonts/Helvetica Neue.eot");"

Tested on Chrome, Firefox,Sarafi, IE9-10-11.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/webfonts/Helvetica Neue.eot");
  src: local("Helvetica Neue"), local("Helvetica Neue"),
    /*url("../fonts/webfonts/Helvetica Neue.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),*/
    url("../fonts/webfonts/Helvetica Neue.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("../fonts/webfonts/Helvetica Neue.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/webfonts/Helvetica Neue.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("../fonts/webfonts/Helvetica Neue.svg") format("svg"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur when you use *desubroutinize*d fonts, which no version of Internet Explorer seems to be able to handle.

If you are generating your font files using [`pyftsubset`](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools/blob/master/Lib/fontTools/subset/__init__.py) from the [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) package, make sure that you do *not* set the `--desubroutinize` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in IE11, I fixed the issue by converting my font file from `.woff2` to `.woff`.

In general, make sure the browser supports the font file format.

Answer (score -1):

hopefully the following note will be useful for you:

> If your fonts are located on a remote server (a CDN for example) they won't render properly in all browsers. That's only partially true. Yes, without an explicit "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header, Firefox and Internet Explorer won't display your webfonts (if you hit F12 to open up Developer Tools in IE and go to the Console tab, you will get the CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted. error) That's simply because IE and Firefox don't allow cross-domain fonts by default. On the other hand Google Chrome will load the fonts without a problem and if you're not aware of the cross-origin issue, debugging this may get really frustrating. While I personally prefer to place my fonts on the same domain too, you can still place them on a remote location and have them load successfuly in all browsers, as long as you add this declaration to your main .htaccess file:
>
> ```
> <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
>       <IfModule mod_headers.c>
>           Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://mydomain.com"
>       </IfModule>
> </FilesMatch>
> ```

[See the reference](http://www.marinbezhanov.com/web-development/16/how-to-embed-webfonts-properly-and-how-to-solve-the-ambiguous-css3111-font-face-encountered-unknown-error/)

Comment: This is not about header access control origin, but CSS3111 error.

Comment: What happens when FF shows the font but IE doesn't? particularly `CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
KlmP_Vc2zOZBldw8AfXD5g.eot` is the error that I get, which I've narrowed down to being the *Lato* font.