# Bootstrap glyphicon shows up but IE11 throws CSS3111 error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-11

Bootstrap glyphicon shows up fine but IE11 console reports `CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error` for these files:

- glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

[image]

This is the Bootstrap override in my stylesheet (only the URL paths were changed):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('../../vendor/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('../../vendor/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../../vendor/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), 
        url('../../vendor/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
        url('../../vendor/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
        url('../../vendor/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Side note:
If I add `!important` after the first `src` url, then the icon **doesn't show up**.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('../../vendor/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot') !important;
...}
```

Using Bootstrap 3.3.4, IE11

How do I get rid of the errors?

Comment: This can  help to you I guess ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559592/ie9-css3111-font-face-encountered-unknown-error

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to a group policy setting called Untrusted Font Blocking. Read more about it here: [IE 11: error CSS3111 in my own code, and google.com/fonts doesn't render any fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023461/ie-11-error-css3111-in-my-own-code-and-google-com-fonts-doesnt-render-any-fon/34070604#34070604)

Answer (score 0):

This can  help to you I guess ...

[IE9 - CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559592/ie9-css3111-font-face-encountered-unknown-error)

and these,

Try this http://fontface.codeandmore.com/blog/ie-7-8-error-with-eot-css3111/ if it may help for the mystery error.

The solution on http://fontface.codeandmore.com now integrated FontForge, so you can just use http://fontface.codeandmore.com to convert your font.

Comment: I would prefer NOT to modify 3rd party files (which is Bootstrap's .eot file,  according to your answer). I don't want to add an unnecessary step to my build process. If someone can verify that this is indeed a Bootstrap issue, then I will file it on their GitHub repo.

Comment: please ... you are always welcome ... make a issue there ... and if you get a proper solution then please post the solution here... it really would be so great for us...