# How to fix CSS311 in IE11 when loading google material icons?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-material-icons

In ie11, I'm loading google material icons

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

but I get this issue

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.
```

Looking up the error online, it says, the binary source is made in a way that doesn't comply with Microsoft standards, but then is there another link I should use for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this article](https://medium.com/@zikaitoh/css3111-and-css3114-issue-640e7d5e9163) and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023461/ie-11-error-css3111-in-my-own-code-and-google-com-fonts-doesnt-render-any-fon).

*CSS3111 could be caused by Windows 10 feature called entrusted font blocking. The untrusted font blocking feature can stop users from loading un-trusted fonts that are process by the Graphics Device Interface (GDI). Un-trusted fonts are any fonts that are installed outside the %windir%Fonts directory.*

**To disable untrusted font blocking using group policy**

1. Open Group Policy Management Editor
2. Under local Computer Policy, expand Computer Configuration, expand Administrative Templates, expand System, and then click Mitigation Options.
3. In the Untrusted Font Blocking setting select Do not block untrusted fonts.

**To disable untrusted font blocking using registry editor**

1. Open Registry Editor (regedit.exe) and go to the following registery subkey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Kernel\
2. If the MitigationOptions key is not there, right click and add a new QWORD (64 bit) value naming it as MitigationOptions.
3. To turn this feature off: Type 2000000000000. and do a computer restart