# CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error” throws for icons created by icomoon app in IE11 when untrusted font blocking is enabled

Tags: css, icons, internet-explorer-11, font-awesome, font-face

I have created font icons through icomoon. And used the below code to add the fonts in the CSS of a web page:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'xlfont';
  src: url('./images/spreadsheet/xlicons.eot?-dzszjm');
  src: url('./images/spreadsheet/xlicons.eot?#iefix-dzszjm') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('./images/spreadsheet/xlicons.woff?-dzszjm') format('woff'), 
  url('./images/spreadsheet/xlicons.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('./images/spreadsheet/xlicons.ttf?-dzszjm') format('truetype'), 
  url('./images/spreadsheet/xlicons.svg?-dzszjm#ssicons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

This is working fine in IE11 until I enabled the option “[untrusted font blocking](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3053676/windows-10-technical-preview-adds-a-feature-that-blocks-untrusted-font)”. Once I enabled this option, I got the following error.

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.
xlicons.eot
```

Anyone else had an issue like this? Could you please give any suggestion are workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the `embedded-opentype` declaration line. If that doesn't work, consider the following from another answer on stack:

> CSS3111 is usually caused by an issue with the font's binary source.
>   One of the popular online TTF to EOT converters for example produces
>   EOT files with a NAME table that doesn't comply to the Microsoft
>   standards, which results in EOT fonts that never load in IE and
>   produce the CSS3111 error. So, when you experience a CSS3111, it is
>   always good to try using a different TTF to EOT converter or font face
>   generator.

OG question: [IE9 - CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559592/ie9-css3111-font-face-encountered-unknown-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Reference: http://marinbezhanov.com/how-to-embed-webfonts-properly-and-how-to-solve-the-ambiguous-css3111-font-face-encountered-unknown-error/