# How can I fix the Font-Face Error in Internet Explorer (without using font-face) [BLAZOR]

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer, blazor, font-face

my Application is a Blazor Server App.
So my problem:
I have a page, which shows a loading screen until the data is loaded. As soon as the data is loaded it displays it in a table. This data I then want to import into Excel (which uses Internet Explorer)

```
if(docs == null) {
    //SHOW LOADING
} else {
    //SHOW DATA IN TABLE
}
```

So I tested it and it worked fine. Then when I checked it sometime later it suddenly stopped working for no reason. It now only shows the Loading Part and never switches (in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox it works just fine.)

Then I looked into the Console of Intenet Explorer and found this Error:

> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.

Since I had no idea what to do I looked it up but found nothing that could help me. I then deleted every font-family keyword in CSS and found no @font-face type. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IE9 - CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559592/ie9-css3111-font-face-encountered-unknown-error)

Comment: No it didn't but I found the error there is a second css file. This one includes @font-face deleted it and now I don't get any errors but it still doesn't work anyway thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I suggest that you clear the cache of IE and try again. Besides, which version of IE are you using? Can you describe more about how does it not working? We can't know the reason from the above description. It may be due to the JavaScript that IE doesn't support during the parsing process of blazor. Please share the components that may cause this problem on the current page and the code that how to get the data.